# eventDrop for Recurring Grouped Events FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

Is there a way to get the new start event of the first and last event in a recurring grouped events?

Like if I drop any events that is in a group into a new date, it will show the start date of the first event as well as the last event since grouped events moves together.

Thank you!

Comment: Not as far as I know, no.